# returning the first found value object

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to find the first found Architect object from an array using the find method. the code should also return null if no architect is found.

I have solved the problem using a for loop. However, I want to complete the problem using the find method

```
function findFirstArchitect(people) {
  /*

        */
       for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (people[i].isArchitect) {

          return people[i]
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

this is what i am trying currently

```
return people.find(arch => arch == isArchitect)? true : null
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: Just `return people.find(arch => arch == isArchitect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you have solved the problem using loops. If that is correct solution then you need to find the first object who has `isArchitect` property.

With `find()` you don't need to compare just return the property `isArchitect` of current object `arch`

```
return people.find(arch => arch.isArchitect) ? true : null
```

The above code will `return` `true` or `null` if you want object itself then use `||` operator

```
return people.find(arch => arch.isArchitect) || null
```

Comment: Thank you all, ive managed to resolve the issues surrounding null. Great help

Comment: @Rowandinho Consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.